# Jquery .on not working on iphone(Only)

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

## Jquery not working on safari mobile on iphone

Hi, I'm working on a dropdwon menu. All of the jquery items are not working on the iphone browser. On all other devices there is no issue.

I'm new learning how to do things with Js and Jquery so I'm little lost.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="seleccionar">
        <form action="php/send_email.php" method="post">
          <select class="marca" id="marca">
            <option value="SHOW"> Selecciona el vehículo que buscas</option>
            <option value="brilliance">Brilliance</option>
            <option value="chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
            <option value="dodge">Dodge</option>
            <option value="ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
            <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
            <option value="kia">Kia</option>
            <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
            <option value="suzuki">Suzuki</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
          </select>
          <select class="modelo" id="modelo">
            <option data-group="SHOW" value="0">Selecciona el modelo</option>
            <option data-group="brilliance" value="v3">v3</option>
            <option data-group="chevrolet" value="tahoe">Tahoe</option>
            <option data-group="dodge" value="durango">Durango</option>
            <option data-group="ford" value="explorer">Explorer</option>
            <option data-group="ford" value="escape">Escape</option>
            <option data-group="ford" value="edge">Edge</option>
            <option data-group="ford" value="ranger">Ranger</option>
            <option data-group="hyundai" value="tucson">Tucson</option>
            <option data-group="hyundai" value="santafe">Santa Fe</option>
            <option data-group="hyundai" value="gi10hb">Grand i10 HB</option>
            <option data-group="hyundai" value="gi10">Grand i10</option>
            <option data-group="jeep" value="gcherokee">Grand Cherokee</option>
            <option data-group="kia" value="sorento">Sorento</option>
            <option data-group="kia" value="sportage">Sportage</option>
            <option data-group="kia" value="rio">Rio</option>
            <option data-group="kia" value="picante">Picanto</option>
            <option data-group="nissan" value="qashqai">Qashqai</option>
            <option data-group="mazda" value="cx9">CX-9</option>
            <option data-group="mazda" value="cx5">CX-5</option>
            <option data-group="mazda" value="cx3">CX-3</option>
            <option data-group="mazda" value="mazda3">Mazda 3</option>
            <option data-group="toyota" value="prado">Prado</option>
            <option data-group="toyota" value="4runner">4 RUNNER</option>
            <option data-group="toyota" value="rav4">RAV-4</option>
            <option data-group="toyota" value="fortuner">Fortuner</option>
            <option data-group="suzuki" value="vitara">Vitara</option>
            <option data-group="suzuki" value="swift">Swift</option>
          </select>
          <select class="age" id="age" name="Menu">
            <option data-group="SHOW" value="0">Selecciona el año</option>
            <option data-group="4runner" value="US$ 63,900">2018</option>
            <option data-group="rav4" value="US$ 32,900">2018</option>
            <option data-group="v3" value="US$ 19,900">2018</option>
            <option data-group="tucson" value="US$ 29,950">2018</option>
            <option data-group="sorento" value="US$ 38,950">2018</option>
            <option data-group="sportage" value="US$ 29,950">2018</option>
            <option data-group="picanto" value="US$ 14,950">2018</option>
            <option data-group="cx9" value="US$ 59,990">2018</option>
            <option data-group="tahoe" value="US$ 63,900">2017</option>
            <option data-group="durango" value="US$ 62,000">2017</option>
            <option data-group="gcherokee" value="US$ 53,000">2017</option>
            <option data-group="mazda3" value="US$ 27,990">2017</option>
            <option data-group="cx3" value="US$ 27,990">2017</option>
            <option data-group="cx5" value="US$ 36,990">2017</option>
            <option data-group="rio" value="US$ 17,950">2017</option>
            <option data-group="edge" value="US$ 45,500">2017</option>
            <option data-group="escape" value="US$ 29,950">2017</option>
            <option data-group="explorer" value="US$ 48,950">2017</option>
            <option data-group="gi10" value="US$ 14,900">2017</option>
            <option data-group="gi10hb" value="US$ 13,900">2017</option>
            <option data-group="santafe" value="US$ 36,900">2017</option>
            <option data-group="prado" value="US$ 79,900">2017 </option>
            <option data-group="qashqai" value="US$ 28,900">2017 </option>
            <option data-group="vitara" value="US$ 22,900">2017 </option>
            <option data-group="ranger" value="US$ 64,900">2017 </option>
            <option data-group="swift" value="US$ 17,900">2017 </option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" value="0" name="price" id="price-m" readonly><a class="precalificate-m" href="#precalificate">Precalifícate</a>
        </form>
      </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(function(){
    $('#marca').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sub = $('#modelo');
        $('option', sub).filter(function(){
            if (
                 $(this).attr('data-group') === val 
              || $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW'
            ) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#marca').trigger('change');
});
  $(function(){
    $('#modelo').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sub = $('#age');
        $('option', sub).filter(function(){
            if (
                 $(this).attr('data-group') === val 
              || $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW'
            ) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#modelo').trigger('change');
});

$(function(){
    $('#age').change(function(){
        var price = $(this).val();
        $('#price-m').val(price);  
    });
});
```

I have posted this code here:
[JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/esabt9k8/)

Comment: i just tried the fiddle on an iPhone 6s running iOS 11. and it works just fine, after selecting form all the drop downs the input value is changed

Comment: try here transauto.com.do/precalificate, not working on my iphone 7 plus, iphone 6 plus and ipad pro either.. but work fine on galaxy s7, galaxy note 5, and galaxy tab.

Comment: iPhone 6s running iOS 11, iPad 2 running iOS 6. Both working just fine. Maybe you're using a content blocking app from the App Store

Comment: Maybe I understood this wrongly: "All of the jquery items are not working on the iphone browse". What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: The problem is after selecting a item on first select input the others drop downs the input value show all options.

Comment: i write other script and work fine on iphone and ipad, i think now is .hide() that doesnt work on iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 0):

This what i do to fix it. i think the problem was .hide()

```
var jsonData = {
      "Data": [{
                "marca":"brilliance",
                "modelo":"V3",
                "age":"2018",
                "price":"US$19,900"
            },{
                "marca":"toyota",
                "modelo":"Fortuner",
                "age":"2017",
                "price":"US$000"
            }]
        };

    $(function(){


        $('#marca').on('change', function(){

            var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Selecciona el modelo</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.length; i++) {

                if(jsonData.Data[i].marca == $(this).val()){
                    listItems += "<option value='" + jsonData.Data[i].modelo + "'>" + jsonData.Data[i].modelo + "</option>";
                }

            }
            $("#modelo").html(listItems);

        });




        $('#modelo').on('change', function(){

            var listAge = '<option selected="selected" value="0">Selecciona el año</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Data.length; i++) {

                if(jsonData.Data[i].modelo == $(this).val()){
                    listAge += "<option value='" + jsonData.Data[i].price + "'>" + jsonData.Data[i].age + "</option>";
                }

            }
            $("#age").html(listAge);

        });


        $('#age').on('change', function(){
            $('#price-m').val($(this).val());
        });

    });
```